# Itext PdfTextExtractor constructor is undefine

Tags: java, itext

I am using Eclipse and iText to read a PDF doc to extract all text and write that text into the file.

I am using this piece of code to extract text from pdf.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("pdftotext.pdf");
PdfTextExtractor extractor = new PdfTextExtractor(reader);        
int pagenumber = reader.getNumberOfPages();
for(int i = 1; i<= pagenumber; i++) {
    System.out.println("============PAGE NUMBER " + i + "=============" );
    String line = extractor.getTextFromPage(i);
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

But I get an error on this line -> `PdfTextExtractor extractor = new PdfTextExtractor(reader);`

I should be able to use PdfTextExtractor, but it gives me a console error:

> `The constructor PdfTextExtractor(PdfReader) is undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [PdfTextExtractor class](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText5/5.5.13.1/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/PdfTextExtractor.html) does not have a public constructor. You could, however, write your code this way:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SRC);
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
      System.out.println("============PAGE NUMBER " + i + "=============" );
      System.out.println(PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i));
}
```

For completion sake, since iText 5 has been deprecated (the code above), here is the exact same code, but for iText 7 (same class - [PdfTextExtractor](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.1.8/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/canvas/parser/PdfTextExtractor.html)):

```
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC));

for (int i = 1; i <= document.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
    System.out.println("============PAGE NUMBER " + i + "=============" );
    System.out.println(PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(document.getPage(i)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support.